# Align right after line break inside an aligned equation

Tags: align

I have a long equation and would like to break into 3 lines at specific places. What I want is to left align A, and right align B and C.

```
\begin{align*}
&A \\
&\hfill +B\\
&\hfill =C
\end{align*}
```

I have tried `\hfill` as above to push B and C to the right side but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Does `&& +B` and `&& =C` do what you desire?

Comment: @Peter Grill: I did, it actually worked with this simple example but I don't know why when the equation gets longer, it pushed B and C out of the right margin (I am working with the two-column format btw - not sure if it matters).

Comment: it is better to work with align (or flalign) than against it.

Comment: @soma: Difficlut to help your further without a representative test case.  It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem. Also, from your description it was not exacly clear what you desired so along with the [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301), I suggest you post an image of the desired result (instead of a description).